# Use js object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I have this js object and I want to "save" the elements "price" in an array, so I can manipulate them. How can I do that?

```
$(function(){
    $("#elastic_grid_demo").elastic_grid({
        'filterEffect': 'scaleup', // moveup, scaleup, fallperspective, fly, flip, helix , popup
        'hoverDirection': true,
        'hoverDelay': 0,
        'hoverInverse': false,
        'expandingSpeed': 500,
        'expandingHeight': 500,
        'items' :
        [
            {
                'price'         : '10.95',
                'title'         : 'Azuki bean',
                'description'   : 'Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage.',
                'thumbnail'     : ['images/small/1.jpg', 'images/small/2.jpg', 'images/small/3.jpg', 'images/small/10.jpg', 'images/small/11.jpg'],
                'large'         : ['images/large/1.jpg', 'images/large/2.jpg', 'images/large/3.jpg', 'images/large/10.jpg', 'images/large/11.jpg'],
                'button_list'   :
                [
                    { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/' },
                    { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                ],
                'tags'          : ['Portrait']
            }, /* ...more items*/
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear. do you want at method that return an array like ['10.95, ....] ?

Comment: Then go with the answer from KooiInc. To use Array.map. Or use http://lodash.com/docs#map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to start by assigning the object passed to elastic_grid into a variable:

```
var opts = {
  'filterEffect': 'scaleup',
   ... 
   ...
   items: [...],
   ...
};
```

Then you can grab just items, and iterate through building a new array of prices:

```
var items = opts.items;
var prices = [];
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  prices.push(items[i].price);
}
// prices populated here
```

Comment: Hi, this works, but only with the first value, prices[0], the rest of prices[] values are "undefined"

Comment: If the data structure is how you posted it, and there are "price" values set... this should definitely work.

Comment: Ok, I had a mistake writing the code, it is ok now, thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) to create an array from an array of objects:

```
var prices = [yourArrayOfObjects].map(function(v) {return v.price;});
```

Answer (score 0):

> price.push(10.95)

creating an array of var price. You can then 'manipulate' the elements in the new array with array methods.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but how can save the object value in the array?